# How do you create a multiboot SCCM task sequence USB Stick?

Tags: usb, task, sequence, boot, sccm

I need to dual boot 2 different task sequences (Win7 images) for different Pc types which require different drivers, we have 2 images one for staff and student which can be added to a particular task sequence.

I need to create a portable solution for cloning without the network using 2 different SCCM  (System Center Configuration Manager) task sequences.  At the moment I go through the usual steps of creating a boot media via the Configuration manager, but there seems to be know way to create a script that changes the task media on the fly so you can select which OS image.

I was looking  at a possible solution using YUMI (a Usb boot tool) but each bootable image requires an ISO.  The task sequence image is around 8GIG.

We use SCCM 2007.  (Still awaiting for a budget to upgrade to 2012 :) )

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to boot two different .WIM images.
Out of the box, I haven't found any tool from MS that will allow this. I have gotten around this discrepancy by renaming the .WIM I want to use to BOOT.WIM in the \SOURCES directory.
That is the name of the .WIM that gets used by all the default settings. You have to rename the file before you attempt to boot from the USB device, but it doesn't take long and could be scripted without much effort.

Theoretically, it should be possible to configure the BCD on the USB device (\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BCD or BOOT\BCD, depending on how the computer is configured to boot) so that you could choose which .WIM to use at boot time without the need to do any messy renaming. I haven't gotten this to work yet (mostly due to lack of time/urgency), but I did write down [what I had done so far](http://thewhackhacker.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/usb-boot-choose-from-multiple-wims/). I found some useful information about booting to .WIM's from [windowsitpro.com](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/q-how-can-i-add-microsoft-windows-imaging-format-wim-based-preinstallation-environment-pe-an).